# document.getElementById(foo).value with html encoded special characters?

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I can't seem to be able to render special chracters in a simple input textfield properly.
For instance in the following

```
&#233;
```

should be é but renders as the raw value

```
document.getElementById("inputKeyword").value ="Cherchez par mot cl&#233;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's html encoding, it has no use in javascript.

```
document.getElementById("inputKeyword").value = "Cherchez par mot clé";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("inputKeyword").value = "Cherchez par mot cl\u00e9";
```